# Win10 hybrid shutdown won't work. Neither will DISM

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, dism

My initial problem is that since I upgraded to Windows 10 computer won't resume after a hybrid shutdown or hibernation, as I explained in more  detail here: [Windows 10 won't shut down properly on ASUS N56V](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-wont-shut-down-properly-on-asus-n56v/9df63895-ce72-4830-9f77-0a6f02de299c?tm=1441047917728).

Following some suggestions given on other threads or forums, I have run `sfc /scannow`, which detects some issues it cannot solve itself.

Then I tried to run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` with no success (I get error 0x800f081f).

Then I burned a Windows 10 DVD and tried with `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:E:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess`. But the laptop does not even read the disc.

What else do I have left to try?

I would like to avoid reinstalling Windows as I may lose some ASUS utilities that are actually useful.

Comment: Why don't you just download those utilities from the ASUS website?

Comment: Ok, I confess I didn't think about it. But is reinstalling Windows really my only chance?

Comment: looks like some fiels are corrupted that were part of newer updates. Those files are not in the install.wim. You can download all released updates and add the MSU files into a new WIM: http://woshub.com/integrate-windows-updates-into-windows-8-image/